# How to get rasa NLU to return address components as entities?

Tags: rasa-nlu

I need my chatbot to query the user for an address and therefore I need the *rasa NLU* to return the address components (e.g. zip code, house number, street name, etc.) contained in the messages as entities.

Of course, one obvious way to do it would be to create a training file containing appropriate training data. But since this surely is a common problem, I hoped there might be another solution. Besides, it is not obvious to me where one might get loads of labeled addresses in various formats.

Comment: Can you share what you have done yet, based on that we can help you further?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I don't quite understand why this is important? My question is basically "what's the best way to get rasa NLU to return the components (street, house number, city,...) of addresses as entities?". I hoped that this could be a collection of strategies, so we can find the "the best". Because I'm pretty sure I'm neither the first nor the last one facing this problem.

Comment: Currently RASA supports simple entities only.

Comment: It isn't a full answer for your question, but this question/answer might suggest an approach that could be expanded on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324733/use-spacy-entities-in-rasa-nlu-training-data

Answer (score 0):

In [this blog post](https://medium.com/rasa-blog/entity-extraction-with-the-new-lookup-table-feature-in-rasa-nlu-94c6c30876a3) some evaluations were done which show that the entity extractor [ner_crf](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/master/components/#ner-crf) performs quite well for addresses if you add enough training data. In the blog post addresses were annotated as follows:

```
Take me to [123 Washington Street](address) please
```

You could support the recognition by supplying some [regular expressions](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/components/#intent-entity-featurizer-regex) 
Depending whether you have a list of possible street names you could also use [lookup tables](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/dataformat/#lookup-tables)